# User Sign out callback in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my project I need to call a callback function on User -> Sign out in order to set as 'null' a Session value.

Is there a way to override `Meteor.logout()` behavior?
How to provide that callback function?

Thanks

Comment: This answer to a similar question may solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19071480/1358220

Answer (score 22):

Meteor.logout() has a callback function.

http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_logout

```
Meteor.logout(function(err) {
  // callback
  Session.set("ses",false);
});
```

--

```
Template.tplName.events
  "click #logout": (e, tmpl) ->
    Meteor.logout ->
      Session.set "ses", false
```