# How to redirect after user has just logged in or just logged out

Tags: meteor, iron-router

It seems Deps.autorun is the way to go but Router.go doesn't seem to work within Deps.autorun.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is an example with three routes: `index`, `signin` and `dashboard`:

```js
Router.configure({layoutTemplate: 'layout'});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', {path: '/'});
  this.route('signin');
  this.route('dashboard');
});

var mustBeSignedIn = function(pause) {
  if (!(Meteor.user() || Meteor.loggingIn())) {
    Router.go('signin');
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
};

var goToDashboard = function(pause) {
  if (Meteor.user()) {
    Router.go('dashboard');
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
};

Router.onBeforeAction(mustBeSignedIn, {except: ['signin']});
Router.onBeforeAction(goToDashboard, {only: ['index']});
```

If a user is on the `index` page and she is logged in, she will automatically be routed to the `dashboard` page. On any page except for `signin`, if the user is not logged in she will be routed to the `signin` page. `onBeforeAction` is reactive so these rules will be enforced immediately if the user logs in or out.

Of course your routes will be different, but hopefully this example illustrates one way to make this work with iron-router.

Also see the [using hooks](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#using-hooks) section of the [iron-router guide](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md).

Comment: Using this approach, you need to create a empty template index. Right? Otherwise, Meteor throws an exception.

Comment: @GiuseppePes I have not found that to be the case. However, in this example the index route isn't meaningful because you always get routed somewhere else, so using a blank or "loading" index template certainly  wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 7):

A few things above seem to be outdated. Here's how I got things working at the present time:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'Layout'
});

Router.map(function() {
    this.route('index', {path: '/'});
    this.route('login');
    this.route('home');
});

var mustBeSignedIn = function() {
    if (!(Meteor.user() || Meteor.loggingIn())) {
        Router.go('login');
    } else {
        this.next();
    }
};
var goHome = function() {
    if (Meteor.user()) {
        Router.go('home');
    } else {
        this.next();
    }
};

Router.onBeforeAction(mustBeSignedIn, {except: ['login']});
Router.onBeforeAction(goHome, {only: ['index', 'login']});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var mustBeSignedIn = function(pause) {
  if (!(Meteor.user() || Meteor.loggingIn())) {
    Router.go('signin');
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
};

var goToDashboard = function(pause) {
  if (Meteor.user()) {
    Router.go('dashboard');
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
};
```

FYI, pause( ) is no supported now, just replace with this.next( )