# Meteor server not redirecting after login

Tags: meteor, user-accounts

I'm trying to make Meteor always redirect to a User's Dashboard after login. For some reason this isn't working. Any ideas?

```
Accounts.onLogin(function() {
  return    Router.render('/dashboard');
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect after user has just logged in or just logged out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900405/how-to-redirect-after-user-has-just-logged-in-or-just-logged-out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was trying to do this in an Accounts document with the onLogin function. It was easily handled in the router.js document as follows:

```
var goToDashboard = function(pause) {
  if (Meteor.user()) {
    Router.go('dashboard');
    pause();
  }
};

Router.onBeforeAction(goToDashboard, {except: ['signin']});
```