# Meteor login - logout ~ hook / callback

Tags: javascript, meteor

Using this package in MeteorJS **accounts-google**, I was trying to find the right approach to have a callback after user login & logout. Currently I am using below hook for login (which seems to me too simplistic -- i want to find a hook that triggered by callback after successful authentication) ~ and still not sure how to do for logout.

`Meteor.autorun(function() {
  if (Meteor.user()) {
//code for login
  }
}`

Comment: one solution here using iron-router and Meteor.user()/Meteor.loggingIn(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900405/how-to-redirect-after-user-has-just-logged-in-or-just-logged-out?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 9):

UPDATE: [There is now an onLogout hook](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsCommon-onLogout)

---

From what I have seen, there are no hooks for the logged out event, but there is one for logged in event:

[Accounts.onLogin(func)](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_onlogin)

The [event-hooks](https://github.com/BenjaminRH/meteor-event-hooks) package adds an onLoggedOut hook.

You could also do something like this:

```
Meteor.autorun(function () {
  if (Meteor.userId()) {
    do something when logged in
  } else {
    do something when logged out
  }
});
```

Comment: Looks like there is onLogout hook now: http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsCommon-onLogout