# Detect if user has been logged out by the server

Tags: meteor

In the route below I'm checking if the user is logged in before rendering the content, but users sometimes gets logged out by the server and get the following message in the console:

```
Error logging in with token: Error: You've been logged out by the server. Please log in again. [403] undefined
```

When this happens, the check for userId() in the route still passes and the user gets a blank page and have to manually navigate to or reload to get to the login page. Is there a more reliable way of checking that the user is logged in and has a valid session going?

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
    name: '_users.currentUser',
    action() {
      if (!Meteor.userId()) {
        FlowRouter.go('/login');
      }    
      mount(LayoutDefaultCtx, {
        content: () => (<UsersSingle _id={Meteor.userId()}/>),
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Picking up meteor.js user logout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923290/picking-up-meteor-js-user-logout)

Comment: As per that OPs comment, "I do want to make sure it's only when they actively log out unfortunately.", that question is about the user actively logging out which is the opposite of what I'm after.

Comment: you're right. sorry, I didn't realize at first that this was on the client.

Comment: does http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsCommon-onLogout not solve your problem?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?